# How to create a table from another table in PowerBI and Sum a column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence

I have a  three tables that looks like this:

| season | production |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| A | 200 |
| A | 40 |
| A | 60 |

| season | production |
| --- | --- |
| B | 11 |
| B | 20 |
| B | 400 |
| B | 600 |

| season | production |
| --- | --- |
| C | 119 |
| C | 212 |
| C | 466 |
| C | 697 |

I want to have a table like this:

| seasons | Total_prodtn | Percentage_Prodtn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | sum from A | % |
| B | sum from A | % |
| c | sum from c | % |

I tried using `DAX` but it did not workout.

any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 :

```
VAR t1=Row("season",VALUES(Table1[season]),"Total_prodtn",SUM(Table1[production]))
VAR t2=Row("season",VALUES(Table2[season]),"Total_prodtn",SUM(Table2[production]))
VAR t3=Row("season",VALUES(Table3[season]),"Total_prodtn",SUM(Table3[production]))
VAR uni=UNION(t1,t2,t3)
RETURN 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        uni
        ,"Percentage_Prodtn",MROUND(DIVIDE([Total_prodtn],Sumx(uni,[Total_prodtn]))*100,2)
    )
```

Solution 2:

```
VAR allInOne =UNION(Table1,Table2,Table3)
        
VAR withTotal =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(allInOne,[season])
        ,"Total_prodtn",VAR s=[season] 
                        RETURN
                            SUMX(
                                FILTER(allInOne,[season]=s)
                                ,[production]
                            )
    )
RETURN 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        withTotal
        ,"Percentage_Prodtn",DIVIDE([Total_prodtn],SUMX(allInOne,[production]))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please test this: I hope It solves your problem.
Note: Result is a table function. Create a new table to test it.

First you need to define a new table:

```
Table4 = UNION(Table1, Table2, Table3)
```

OR
Using Table constructors {}:

```
Table4 = {
("A",12),("A",200),("A",40),("A",60),
("B",11),("B",20),("B",400),("B",600),
("C",119),("C",212),("C",466),("C",697)
}
```

Resulting Table:

[image: Click here to see image]

Then create a 2nd table and paste this code:

```
FinalTable = ADDCOLUMNS (
SUMMARIZE(Table4, [season]),
"Total_prodtn", CALCULATE(SUM(Table4[production])),
"Percentage_Prodtn", DIVIDE ( CALCULATE(SUM(Table4[production])),
CALCULATE(SUM(Table4[production]),ALL(Table4)))
)
```

If we test the FinalTable, Results produced:

[image: Click to see final image]

I hope It solves your problem.

Comment: I used `CombinTable` as the new table that will hold the return values from `Table1 -3` but i got an error `can not find Total_prodtn, production`. I then create a table with `Total_prodtn, ` as column , but still didnt work

Comment: Hello, I updated the solution. please test it. :)